# Sublime Text 3 + LaTeXing + Knitr setup does not work

Tags: latex, installation, sublimetext, knitr, sublimetext3

For my **Sublime Text 3 + LaTeXing + Knitr** setup, I followed the instructions closely (or at least I thought I did) from the LaTeXing website tutorial here: http://www.latexing.com/docs/stable/tutorials/knitr-with-latexing.html

When attempting run the [example code](http://www.latexing.com/docs/stable/tutorials/knitr-with-latexing.html) given in the tutorial, I got the following error/log message. **What went wrong?** Thanks!

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX) (format=pdflatex 2014.1.17)  19 JAN 2014 11:04
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"D:/Dropbox/temp/test.tex"
! Emergency stop.
<*> "D:/Dropbox/temp/test.tex"

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5 strings out of 493308
 173 string characters out of 6141367
 52419 words of memory out of 5000000
 3564 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 0i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```